# SQL Query Group by column values, and get o/p as separate column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
+----------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+
| student_serial | reg_date            | batch_serial | status |
+----------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+
|              1 | 2019-10-31 10:25:17 |            1 | C      |
|              2 | 2019-10-31 10:32:45 |            3 | A      |
|              3 | 2019-11-04 10:57:51 |            1 | A      |
+----------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+
```

And I want the o/p as

```
batch_serial count_a count_c
1            1       1
3            1       0
```

i.e. the o/p must group by the values of status column, and display it as separate column

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    batch_serial
    sum(status = 'A') count_a,
    sum(status = 'C') count_c
from mytable 
group by batch_serial
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation.  In MySQL, this looks like:

```
select batch_serial, sum( status = 'A' ) as count_a, sum( status = 'C' ) as count_c
from t
group by batch_serial;
```